# FQL Javascript Bug Workaround: Search for id from name

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a workaround for the current bug in FQL: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/266794040030851?browse=search_4f2ff35cf1e521b94883666

The idea would be to request `SELECT id FROM user WHERE name="First last"` but there is currently a bug in the index such that you can't search by name.
I need to find someones facebook id from their full-name, preferably ordered by mutual friends. I've tried the facebook search api but haven't found it reliable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is an ugly workaround but you have to go outside FQL:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=id,name,link&q=|name|&type=user&access_token=MY_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN

Using search API this might work, where there is |name| you should just put "Name Surname".

EDIT:

Beware: A facebook app cannot have MORE privileges than a facebook user, ok I'm expanding what I'm trying to say: As you know a facebook user can modify his account settings in order to be **NOT visible in public search** that means EVERY search will not display that particular user... if the user you are trying to search has this particular setting, then you won't see him, not even through FQL!

[This is where a facebook user can set this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZZG2.jpg)

Comment: Yeaaaa I mentioned that I tried that, but it doesn't always give me results. Maybe some of my subjects have privacy settings that don't let their info be accessed by apps...which makes things difficult. No workaround at that point I guess?

Comment: Are you sure? all the names I tried worked out and i received the correct ID... does your token has all the permissions?
Let's say that the name is "Barak Obama" and the access token is "AAA" write me an example of your call

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=id,name,link&q=Barak+Obama&type=user&access_token=AAA

It works for some people, but not all people.

Comment: sorry that one cut out because it was a hyperlink i guess. I took out the https: "graph.facebook.com/search?fields=id,name,link&q=barak+obama&type=user&access_token=AAA"

Comment: There is only one kind of users I miss in this search, and I've just added some information to my answer to explain why some user cannot be "searched", hope that helps.

Comment: I have a user, who I can search in the normal search box on facebook. If I just put in her first name her name appears and I can click on it. I actually have multiple..obviously I can't post their names. Pretty weird. Must just be a bug?

Comment: Is this user a friend of yours (in facebook I mean)? If not, have you any friends in common with her (or him)? If one of this two is true, then it is possible that YOU can actually see her in a search in facebook site, but NOT in with facebook API even if your token is valid. For example: My personal FB account cannot be "searched by name" if you are not my friend, as you can see in the image I linked in my answer. And if I try to search my user, YES MYSELF, my name and my surname, the search results is an empty JSON Array, and this is not a bug, it's just facebook privacy policies :-)